# Analyzing circuit with two transformers in parallel

Tags: circuit-analysis, inductor, impedance, modeling

I'm interested in analyzing a circuit with two transformers in it. The tricky thing about it is that the transformers are in "parallel" around the same loop, so I can't just use the usual trick of multiplying the effective impedances by N^2 to simplify the circuit.

Here's the circuit in question:
[image: epicyclic geartrain circuit diagram]

For the curious, this is a circuit built using the impedance analogy for mechanical systems in which torque is analogous to voltage and velocity (\$ \dot{\theta}\$) is analogous to current. My goal is to be able to write transfer functions for the relationship between \$\tau_{em}/\tau_{op}\$ and \$\tau_{em}/\tau_{od}\$ and \$\tau_{op}/\tau_{od}\$.

How can I write equations for the voltage across the two transformers? I was thinking that I could perhaps create two separate circuits and solve some system of equations but I haven't been able to find any examples of this so far.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few models that you can use:

The transformer equations for an ideal transformer with resistance are as follows:

$$ V_1 = L_1\frac{di_1}{dt}+M_s*I_1$$
$$ V_2 = L_2\frac{di_2}{dt}+M_s*I_2$$

Ms is the coupling coefficent.

[image: schematic]

There is the T-model which might be useful in simplifying inductors

[image]

Matrix math might be good at this point (write out a series of equations)
Good luck on the simplification